# Query errors when GROUP BY statement is not commented out

Tags: sql-server

Unable to understand why all incidents of '@column_name' are correctly interpreted except when GROUP BY statement is processed.

Error statement: Incorrect syntax near 'BYclaim_number'.

```
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT ' + @column_Name + 
    ' FROM [qlx_dq_scrcrd].[dbo].[claims4]
      WHERE len(' + @column_name + ')!=' + @stndLengthChar + 
    ' AND process_date = ' + QUOTENAME(@procDateChar, '''') +   
    ' AND client =' + QUOTENAME(@client, '''')  + 
    ' GROUP BY' + @column_Name + 
    ' ORDER BY 1 desc;'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Comment: You're missing a space after "GROUP BY"

Comment: Your question was answered already, but also I recommend not breaking up your query as it makes it vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the text `BYclaim_number` because the `GROUP BY` line of your code lacks a trailing space, so BY is being directly concatenated with the contents of @column_name.

Here's the corrected code...

```
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT ' + @column_Name + 
    ' FROM [qlx_dq_scrcrd].[dbo].[claims4]
      WHERE len(' + @column_name + ')!=' + @stndLengthChar + 
    ' AND process_date = ' + QUOTENAME(@procDateChar, '''') +   
    ' AND client =' + QUOTENAME(@client, '''')  + 
    ' GROUP BY ' + @column_Name + 
    ' ORDER BY 1 desc;'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Comment: Thanks; something so simple . . .

Comment: @JesseReyes Accept it as answer then please.